# How to declare an array with size modification in a subroutine?

Tags: fortran, subroutine

I did a subroutine `MatPath` to append an array but I don't understand how I should declare this array in the subroutine where I call `MatPath` :

```
!********************************************************************** 
SUBROUTINE MatPath(Path, Start) 
INTEGER(2),PARAMETER::Ximax = 5, Yimax = 5, Zimax = 1
INTEGER(4)::W,B
REAL(8), DIMENSION(:,:), ALLOCATABLE::Path
REAL(8), DIMENSION(:,:), ALLOCATABLE::Temp_Array
REAL(8), DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE::Start
W=SIZE(Path,DIM=2)
ALLOCATE(Temp_Array(3,W))
DEALLOCATE(Path)
ALLOCATE(Path(3,W+1))
Path(:,1:W)=Temp_Array(:,1:W)
Path(:,W+1)=Start(:)
DEALLOCATE(Temp_Array)

RETURN
END SUBROUTINE MatPath
!************************************************
SUBROUTINE FINDPATH(Array, St)
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER(4), DIMENSION(3,3)::Array
REAL(8), DIMENSION(3)::St
REAL(8), DIMENSION(3, :)::Path !PROBLEM HERE

CALL MatPath(Path, St)

END SUBROUTINE FINDPATH
```

It's still unclear how I can declare an array which the size would be modify in a subroutine ... If someone can explain how it work, Thanks !

***EDIT***

To be more clear here a simplification of my problem how can I get modification of the size of my array `A` and pass it between the main program end the subroutine ? :

```
program teste10

REAL(8),DIMENSION(:,:),ALLOCATABLE::A

ALLOCATE(A(2,2))
A=1
WRITE(*,*), "Initial A : ", A

CALL TESTE1(A)

WRITE(*,*) "new A : ", A 

DEALLOCATE(A)
STOP
end program teste10
!**********************************************
SUBROUTINE TESTE1(A)

REAL(8),DIMENSION(:,:),INTENT(INOUT), ALLOCATABLE::A
REAL(8), DIMENSION(:,:), ALLOCATABLE::Temp
INTEGER(4)::X, Y

X=SIZE(A, DIM=1)
Y=SIZE(A, DIM=2)
ALLOCATE(Temp(X,Y))
DEALLOCATE(A)
ALLOCATE(A(X+2,Y+3))
A(1:X, 1:Y)=Temp(1:X,1:Y)
A(X+1:X+2, Y+1:Y+3)=0
DEALLOCATE(Temp)

RETURN
END SUBROUTINE TESTE1
```

When I try to do that it give me a `"SIGSEV, segmentation fault occured"` or just run forever without any message....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there was certainly some error message from the compiler. Please show your error messages in our questions.

In the *called* subroutine, you declare the dummy arguments `allocatable`. That is correct.

In the *calling* subroutine, you didn't declared the arrays `allocatable`. That is not correct. If you pass any variable into an allocatable dummy argument, the variable must itself be allocatable.

So both `Path` and `St` **have to be allocatable** inside `FINDPATH`.

You probably can remove the `allocatable` attribute from `Start` and then `St` will not have to be `allocatable` either.

So (not tested):

```
!********************************************************************** 
SUBROUTINE MatPath(Path, Start) 
  INTEGER  ::  W
  REAL(something_better), DIMENSION(:,:), ALLOCATABLE :: Path
  REAL(something_better), DIMENSION(:,:), ALLOCATABLE :: Temp_Array
  REAL(something_better), DIMENSION(:),               :: Start

  W=SIZE(Path,DIM=2)
  ALLOCATE(Temp_Array(3,W))
  DEALLOCATE(Path)
  ALLOCATE(Path(3,W+1))
  Path(:,1:W)=Temp_Array(:,1:W)
  Path(:,W+1)=Start(:)
  DEALLOCATE(Temp_Array)
END SUBROUTINE MatPath
!************************************************


SUBROUTINE FINDPATH(Array, St)
  INTEGER, DIMENSION(3,3) :: Array
  REAL(something_better), DIMENSION(3) :: St
  REAL(something_better), DIMENSION(3, :), allocatable :: Path 

  CALL MatPath(Path, St)

  !here do something with Path and Array?
  !it is not clear what does Path and what does Array
END SUBROUTINE FINDPATH
```

---

Moreover, the presence of `IMPLICIT NONE` in the calling subroutine is leading me to suspicion that your subroutines are not in a module. They **have to** be in a module or the explicit interface must be established by some other means because allocatable arguments require explicit interface.

---

The second version (also not tested):

```
module Subroutines
  implicit none
  integer, parameter :: dp = kind(1.d0)

contains

    SUBROUTINE TESTE1(A)
      REAL(dp), DIMENSION(:,:), INTENT(INOUT), ALLOCATABLE :: A
      REAL(dp), DIMENSION(:,:), ALLOCATABLE :: Temp
      INTEGER :: X, Y

      X=SIZE(A, DIM=1)
      Y=SIZE(A, DIM=2)
      ALLOCATE(Temp(X,Y))
      DEALLOCATE(A)
      ALLOCATE(A(X+2,Y+3))
      A(1:X, 1:Y) = Temp(1:X,1:Y)
      A(X+1:X+2, Y+1:Y+3) = 0
      DEALLOCATE(Temp)
    END SUBROUTINE TESTE1

end module


program teste10
  use Subroutines

  implicit none

  REAL(dp), DIMENSION(:,:), ALLOCATABLE :: A

  ALLOCATE(A(2,2))
  A=1
  WRITE(*,*), "Initial A : ", A

  CALL TESTE1(A)

  WRITE(*,*) "new A : ", A 

  DEALLOCATE(A)
end program teste10
```

---

Here insert my usual rant about ugliness and non-portability of `integer(4)` and `real(8)`.

I can't imagine why you  might want

```
INTEGER(2),PARAMETER::Ximax = 5, Yimax = 5, Zimax = 1
```

instead of just

```
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: Ximax = 5, Yimax = 5, Zimax = 1
```

There is simply no reason why the former might be better unless you pass it as an argument somewhere where kind 2 is required.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I don't understand the part about modules ? My entire code is in the same page and I'm calling one subroutine in an other, or in the main program.... I also edit my post with the test i'm doing

Comment: You **HAVE TO** use modules. The subroutines have to be in a module. Or you could move the subroutines between `CONTAINS` and `END PROGRAM` but that is good only for short programs. It does not matter if the subroutines are in the same source file or not.

Comment: What happens if the the array is INTENT(OUT)? Would it get automatically allocated in the subroutine?

Comment: If it is intent(out) it gets deallocated, not allocated.